# F# 3.0 LINQ groupBy sample mistake

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#

I am learning LINQ with F# 3.0. Try to follow the examples by "Query Expressions (F#)" from this URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I have created a simple data table in SQL Server 2008 R2, the database name is myDatabase.
Create a simple data table as indicated in the sample:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
    [StudentID] INT           NOT NULL,
    [Name]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Age]       INT           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentID] ASC)
);

Then add a few rows:

INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, Name, Age)
VALUES(1, 'Abercrombie, Kim', 10);
INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, Name, Age)
VALUES(2, 'Abolrous, Hazen', 14);
INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, Name, Age)
VALUES(3, 'Hance, Jim', 12);
INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, Name, Age)
VALUES(4, 'Adams, Terry', 12);
INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, Name, Age)
VALUES(5, 'Hansen, Claus', 11);

Try to understand what is groupBy in the sample, the following is my code:

```
#light
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq

[<Generate>]
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=True">
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()

let groupX = 
    query {
          for student in db.Student do
          groupBy student.Age into g
          select (g.Key, g.Count())
          }
```

However, I got compiler error:
Error The field, constructor or member 'Count' is not defined

I am thinking Count() is a built-in function, but it is not.
Tell me how I can use the sample code.  Or, if it is a mistake, show me the code can do the job.
By the way, I believe another sample: groupValBy has the same issue.
The code sample from the web site is:

```
query {
      for student in db.Student do
      groupValBy student.Name student.Age into g
      select (g, g.Key, g.Count())
      }
```

Let me know if I miss something or think wrongly.
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you miss

```
open System.Linq
```

The `Count()` is an extension method defined there.

Comment: Hi, Wiktor: great! Your advice is correct.  However, for the sample code on internet, there is no such open System.Linq.  Therefore, I guess not only me, but also many other people may not know this!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the .NET extension method `Count()`, then Wiktor's answer is the way to go. I think that's actually the best approach in your case. However, you can also write the query alternatively, using standard F# functions from the `Seq` module:

```
query { for student in db.Student do 
        groupValBy student.Name student.Age into g 
        select (g.Key, Seq.length g) }
```

In this case, the `g.Count()` syntax is shorter, but in a more complex query, the `Seq` functions and F# pipelining operator `|>` may work nicer, because the F# type inference works better for them.

Comment: Hi Tomas: you always provide good answers.  Your code seem easier to understand!  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tomas: is F#'s Linq2SQL smart enough to translate Seq.length to a SQL's COUNT(*) or the select will be executed in memory?

Comment: @Wiktor : I'm curious about that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old but I had same issue as OP recently

count can be added as last statement see below

dont forget namespace of
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers

Note also the representation of Tdate as Tdate.Value.Date this gets around the problem with Nullable types in f# linq queries.

```
let distinctCounts = 
    query {
        for row in db.TblTable do
        where (row.Tdate.Value.Date >= stdate && row.Tdate.Value.Date <= enddate)
        let key2 = AnonymousObject<_,_>(row.Key, row.Tdate)
        groupBy key2
        count
        }
```